# How to append text in a form using ajax/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form. Let's called it myform.

Inside there are checkboxes, such as these two:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='power_convention[]' value='SOME VALUE #1' />
<input type='checkbox' name='power_evidence[]' value='SOME VALUE #2' />
```

At the end of the form, there's a textarea.

```
<textarea id="elm1" name="comments" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">
```

If power_convention is checked, I want it to immediately append the value of that checkbox into the `comments` checkbox with the following structure:

```
<h3>SOME VALUE #1</h3><br />
```

Similarly, if power_evidence is clicked, I want it to do the same thing, but obviously after whatever came before it.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jQuery solution:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var val = "<h3>" + this.value + "</h3><br />";
    if(this.checked) {
        $('#elm1').val(function(i, v) {
            return v + val;
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#elm1').val(function(i, v) {
            return v.replace(new RegExp(val), '');
        });
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/Xyv5C/)

This only works if `val` does not contain any special regular expressions characters. In this case [you would have to escape them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript).

**Update:** Actually, you don't need a regular expression here, `v.replace(val, '')` will be just fine (thanks @Pinkie);

An alternative to regular expressions would be to recreate the content of the textarea:

```
var $inputs = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
$inputs.change(function() {
    var val = "<h3>" + this.value + "</h3><br />";
    if(this.checked) {
        $('#elm1').val(function(i, v) {
            return v + val;
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#elm1').val('');
        $inputs.not(this).change();
    }
});
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/Xyv5C/2/)

Comment: This looks great on fiddle! The only problem I'm having seems to be that it's conflicting with my textarea WYSIWYG editor called tinyMCE.  Is there a way to get it to work with that?

Comment: @zackt147: What kind of conflict?

Comment: Simply that clicking the checkbox doesn't do anything when the tinymce js is loaded. I'm not sure how to tell what's going wrong exactly.  Here's the js file:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js

Comment: @zackt147: Probably because tinyMCE replaces the textarea with some other element so that it can style the text. I suggest you have a look at the API. There must be a way to set the content of the editor.

Comment: @zackt147: See http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.setContent and http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent

Comment: Instead of `$('#elm1').val(function(i, v) { return v + val;});`, you just write `tinyMCE.get('elm1').setContent(tinyMCE.get('elm1').getContent() + val)`. (And of course `tinyMCE.get('elm1').setContent('')` to clear the content.)

Comment: You sir, are a god. Thank you infinitely.

Comment: Nice solution. Is there a reason why you used regexp and did `v.replace(new RegExp(val), '');` rather then doing without regexp like `v.replace(val, '');`

Comment: @Pinkie: Good question. I think I was so used to use regular expressions with `replace` that I forgot that you can just pass a string. Updated.

Comment: Hey Felix, should the tinyMCE uncheck code be resetting the entire textbox? That's what it's doing when something is unchecked, whereas the original retained the text that didn't belong to the box being unchecked.

Comment: @zackt147: What exactly do you mean? That the tinyMCE content is reset but the actual textarea is not?

Comment: For example, if two things are checked, and I uncheck one of them, both things disappear in the textarea.

Comment: @zackt147: No that should not happen. Try `tinyMCE.get('elm1').setContent(tinyMCE.get('elm1').getContent().replace(val, ''))` in the `else` block.

Comment: Hmm. No dice. Here's the code: `$(window).load(function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var val = "<h3>" + this.value + "</h3><br />";
    if (this.checked) {
tinyMCE.get('elm1').setContent(tinyMCE.get('elm1').getContent() + val)
    }
    else {
tinyMCE.get('elm1').setContent(tinyMCE.get('elm1').getContent().replace(val, ''))
    }
});
  }); `

(Now it doesn't delete it at all)

Comment: @zackt147: Could you please create a complete example at  http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/ ?

Comment: @zack147: Ok, the reason why `replace` did not work was that tinyMCE changes the HTML you set. The `<br />` is transformed into `<p>&nbsp;</p>`. If you remove the tag, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/664eY/2/

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery**

```
$('input[name="power_convention[]"]').click(function() {
    // assuming you only want the value if the checkbox is being ticked
    // not when it's being unticked
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#elm1').val("<h3>" + this.value + "</h3><br />");
    }
});
```

If you want them both to insert into the same `textarea` (and they're the only fields on the page that begin with *power_*) then you can change the selector to use
jQuery's [Attribute Starts With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
`$('input[name^="power_"]`
```

[**Demo on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/ysvCh/).

Comment: Woo! Thanks! How about removal for unchecking?

Comment: @zackt147: Just clearing the textarea? Or removing the specific entry added by the checkbox? If it's the former, then just add `else {     $('#elm1').val(""); }` after the `if`.  If it's the latter... that's a job for another day!

Comment: Actually, just go with Felix's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to add an onClick event handler to your checkbox:

```
<input type='checkbox' onClick="someFunction(this)" name='power_convention[]' value='SOME VALUE #1' />
```

Then, up in the head section, in a script tag, put

```
someFunction(checkbox) {
    document.getElementById("elm1").value += "<h3>" + checkbox.value + "</h3>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyRR7/16/)

```
$('input:checkbox[name*=power_]').click(function(){
   value = '<h3>' + $(this).val() + '</h3> <br />'; 
    prevVal = $('#elm1').val();


    $('#elm1').val(prevVal  + value );
});
```